# How with shade and standalone

Tags: standalone

I want draw a figure like fig 1, but my Latex give fig 2.
I think the problem is in:

```
\shade[top ‎color=blue!2‎0‎‎] (‎-‎‎‎1,‎-1.2‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎) rectangle (‎3‎‎‎,‎3‎);‎‎
```

‎‎[image]

Here is the Latex code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decoration={aspect=0.3, segment length=1.5mm, amplitude=2.4mm,coil},decorate] (1,5) -- (1,3.3);
\fill [pattern = north east lines] (-0.5,5) rectangle (2.5,5.2);
\draw[thick] (-0.5,5) -- (2.5,5);
%\filldraw[fill=blue!20, draw=blue!60] (-1,-1.2) rectangle (3,3);
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (1,3.3) -- (1,2.5);
\draw[line width=1pt] (-1,3) -- (3,3);

\draw[->] (1,0.2) -- (1,-0.8);
\node[draw=none,right=.1cm] at (1.3,4.25) (a) {$K$};
\node[draw=none,right=.1cm] at (0,-0.5) (a) {$f(t)$};
\draw[line width=6pt] (1,2.5) -- (1,-0.2);
\shade[top color=blue!20] (-1,-1.2) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is not correct!

Comment: You only uploaded one image. Is this image what the result *should* look like?

Comment: sorry I can not upload incorrect figure.

Comment: However, you can run this code and obtained it

Comment: Ok, no problem, so the result should look like the image you have shown?

Comment: yes, I have a problem with "\documentclass{standalone}".

Comment: In "\documentclass{article}" everything's is right.

Comment: If I copy the code in your question, changing between `standalone` and `article` doesn't make a difference. Can you check my answer, does this solve your problem?

Comment: I want obtained a figure in whole page, not only in a corner, and it is possible by `standalone`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46544/discussion-between-nima-and-hbaderts).

Comment: Try it with the `preview` class option.

Answer (score 1):

When drawing a TikZ picture, you should always start with things in the background, and then add objects which are in front of that. Take the following example:

```
\draw[red,fill] (0,0) circle (0.1);
\draw[blue,fill] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
```

The result of this will be only the rectangle, as the circle is *behind* the rectangle.

The same happened to your figure: By placing the `\shade` command at the bottom of your code, i.e. as the last command, this shaded rectangle is shown in the foreground, while you actually want it to be in the background. As a solution, simply move the command to the start of your `tikzpicture`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% First draw the background
\shade[top color=blue!20] (-1,-1.2) rectangle (3,3);

\draw[decoration={aspect=0.3, segment length=1.5mm, amplitude=2.4mm,coil},decorate] (1,5) -- (1,3.3);
\fill [pattern = north east lines] (-0.5,5) rectangle (2.5,5.2);
\draw[thick] (-0.5,5) -- (2.5,5);
%\filldraw[fill=blue!20, draw=blue!60] (-1,-1.2) rectangle (3,3);
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (1,3.3) -- (1,2.5);
\draw[line width=1pt] (-1,3) -- (3,3);

\draw[->] (1,0.2) -- (1,-0.8);
\node[draw=none,right=.1cm] at (1.3,4.25) (a) {$K$};
\node[draw=none,right=.1cm] at (0,-0.5) (a) {$f(t)$};
\draw[line width=6pt] (1,2.5) -- (1,-0.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and you'll get exactly the desired result:

[image: result]

Comment: sorry, but in my result the background is disappear!

Comment: If you copy&paste exactly the code in my answer to a new document and compile it, do you get the same result as my image?

Comment: I done it, but ...., I think it is a counterexample. maybe my computer does not work correct!

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date latex installation?  You can open you `xy.log` file, and the first line should say sth like "This is pdfTeX, Version ..., (TeX Live 2016)" - I am interested in the last part: can you post the "TeX Live 20xx" (maybe it is also "MikTeX xyz") here?

Comment: many thanks. If it is possible to you, please send to me .EPS of figure. I think my Latex is old and does not work well. (esmaeilimath@gmail.com)

Comment: Sure, I uploaded it to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzrz05yl1avoykd/image.pdf?dl=0). I'd suggest to update your LaTeX installation when you have some spare time. I always try to stay up-to-date, as many packages are actively developed and improved.